# Click a LinkButton with javascript in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Ive got several LinkButtons inside a Repeater. When I manually click on them, they do a postback nicely. All my tries to click on a LinkButton through javascript have failed, and Im now running out on ideas (and so are Google, cant seem to find any other options). I have tried to alternate between OnClick and OnCommand.

LinkButtons:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repItems_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlItem" runat="server">                       
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkItem" runat="server" OnClick="lnkItem_OnClick" OnCommand="lnkItem_OnCommand"></asp:LinkButton>                  
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>        
</asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript:

```
eval(LinkButton.attr('href'); //Causes Sys.ParameterCountException
LinkButton.click();           //Nothing happens (no click event on LinkButton)
LinkButton.trigger('click');  //Same as LinkButton.click()
```

If i set OnClientClick to do the postback, the click() functions starts working, but I get Sys.ParameterCountException error again:

```
lnkItem.OnClientClick = String.Format("__doPostBack('{0}', '');", lnkItem.UniqueID);
```

Some have suggested to change ScriptManager to release mode, but that didnt trigger the postback, it just removed the error message.

`eval(LinkButton.attr('href');` does work in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what issue you're running into, but the following works for me.

ASCX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlItem" runat="server">                       
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' OnClick="lnkItem_OnClick" OnCommand="lnkItem_OnCommand"></asp:LinkButton>                  
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>        
</asp:Repeater>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('MainContent_repItems_lnkItem_0').click(); return false;">Huzzah!</button>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Item> test = new List<Item>();
        test.Add(new Item { Text = "Item 1" } );
        test.Add(new Item { Text = "Item 2" } );
        repItems.DataSource = test;
        repItems.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lnkItem_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = ((LinkButton)sender).Text });
    }

    protected void lnkItem_OnCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = ((LinkButton)sender).Text });
    }
```

Both OnClick and OnCommand fire in this example.